# How do I check if my executable is running for a service or for a normal program?

Tags: c, windows, windows-services, mingw

I'm developing a win service in using `mingw` I've been trying for hours
I looked for examples on the internet I used `ChatGPT`
and nothing it returned works and the few examples I found
had nothing to do with what I wanted

I hope there is some way to do this the
idea and before i create the `SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRY` i can check if my executable was started
for a windows service,
if yes i create the
`SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRY` if I don't do anything else.

Answer (score 0):

If your program supports multiple modes then I would suggest using a command line parameter like `/service` for the service registration.

Alternatively you could check if your process token contains `S-1-5-6` (SECURITY_SERVICE_RID) but I'm not sure which Windows version that was introduced.

Answer (score 0):

I saw a simple way to check this just create `SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRY` and use `StartServiceCtrlDispatcher` if it returns an error probably the executable was started like a normal program.

```
SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRY _dispatcher_entry_table[] = 
{

    {"", (LPSERVICE_MAIN_FUNCTION)serviceMain},

    {NULL, NULL}

};

if (!StartServiceCtrlDispatcher(_dispatcher_entry_table))
{

    DWORD __error_code = GetLastError();

    if (__error_code == ERROR_FAILED_SERVICE_CONTROLLER_CONNECT)
    {

         //It's probably a normal program

    }
    else
    {

         //handle the errors

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if it's running you should check if the service is running. Check under services by running `services.msc` and looking for the service you registered.

Some time ago I wrote a simple library to make your program a service (on Windows) or daemon (on *nix):
https://sourceforge.net/projects/daemonservice/

Maybe you can check the source on how it was done there...